# DateTime as optional parameter (default to "now", not null)?

Tags: php, datetime, parameters

Is possible to set a `DateTime` object as optional parameter using `now` as default?

The following code gives me a **syntax error**:

```
public function getData(array $metrics, DateTime $start,
    DateTime $end = new DateTime, $params = array())
{
    // Default DateTime constructor automatically use "now"
}
```

It's just a matter of curiosity, **i know i can do**:

```
public function getData(array $metrics, DateTime $start,
    DateTime $end = null, $params = array())
{
    $end = is_null($end) ? new DateTime() : null;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you cannot set an object as a default function/method parameter.  From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default):

> **Default argument values**
>   A function may define C++-style default values for **scalar** arguments ...

An object is not a [scalar datatype](http://www.php.net/manual/language.types.intro.php).